# When does a comma change the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, punctuation, commas

Match the two sentences with their meaning:

> 1) I had a discussion with a friend and a programmer.
>
> 2) I had a discussion with a friend, and a programmer.

Meanings:

> a) I talked to a friend who *is* a programmer.
>
> b) I talked to *two* people, a friend, and a programmer.

Intuitively, I know that 1 => a, and 2 => b. Is there a rule? Does this grammatical construct have a formal name or definition?

Comment: "Let's eat, Grandma!" vs. "Let's eat Grandma!"

Comment: "A woman, without her, man is nothing." vs "A woman without her man, is nothing."

Comment: I agree with Kris's answer that both sentences have meaning 2.  To achieve meaning 1 within the confines of your given sentence structure, I think you have to go for "I had a discussion with a friend and programmer."

Comment: Sometimes a sentences can be interpreted in two different ways without comma, like: "call me a cab" :)

Comment: @kris, sorry, I forgot abound this thread! Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"I had a discussion with a friend and a programmer" does not mean "I talked to a friend who is a programmer". Both 1) and 2) have the same meaning b). However, the use of comma before *and* is now discouraged by some and flagged by some software.

For the first meaning, you would say "I had a discussion with my friend, a programmer" or better still, "I had a discussion with a programmer friend".

Comment: Generally, grammatical errors are difficult to identify and rectify in speech. Reading and writing will help in this case.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I think the sentence is an unlikely one anyway.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I think it is more common in speech than in writing.

Comment: I meant that it was semantically unlikely that 'friend' and 'programmer' would appear like this in the same sentence. 'I had a discussion with a web designer and a programmer' would of course be quite natural, and it would be clear that they were two different people.

Comment: @Barrie England, so how would you reference a single person who is a designer and a programmer, and there was a contextual reason to declare both?

Comment: Not using the comma before _and_ (the serial comma) can make a phrase ambiguous; try interpreting the following phrase: "To my parents, the Pope and Mother Theresa."

Comment: @Mohamad: I’d have to say something like 'I had a discussion with a web designer, who happens to be a programmer as well.'

Comment: @Mohamad - it's why you always try and avoid commas in legal documents like contracts and patents. Arguing over the meaning of a comma has made lawyers a lot of money!

Comment: To me, the only thing the comma signifies in that sentence is a pause before the word "and".

Comment: This question would not be complete without a reference to the marvellous book "[Eats, Shoots and Leaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_%26_Leaves)" and the joke it takes its title from.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Good point.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: Only Americans avoid punctuation in legal documents. The rest of the English-speaking world finds punctuation to be an aid to comprehension.

Comment: @Marcin - canadians didn't http://www.theglobeandmail.com/report-on-business/article838561.ece

Comment: @MartinBeckett: I don't really see your point. That mostly illustrates that Canadian lawyers use punctuation.

Comment: @Marcin - actually it demonstrates that they shouldn't have !

Comment: Nobody mentioned "An Officer and a Gentleman" yet?

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There should not be a comma before *and* in any case as there are only two items.

> I had a discussion with a friend and a programmer

could mean either you had a discussion with two people or only one who is both a friend and a programmer, but in the absence of further context, it is usually taken to mean the former.

For example, it would be clear and correct if you had written

> I had a discussion with a friend and a programmer. His name is Darren.

This would mean that you had a discussion with Darren who is both your friend and a programmer.

Comment: Kris claims that both 1 and 2 have meaning b. You disagree with that. Can you give me a reason, please?

Answer (score 4):

1) I had a discussion with a friend and a programmer. - This could be one or two people.
2) I had a discussion with a friend, and a programmer. - This sentence is wrong. The comma is incorrect there, whether this describes one or two people.
a) I talked to a friend who is a programmer. - This is only one person.
b) I talked to two people, a friend, and a programmer. - This is not two people. This indicates **FOUR** people! (two people, plus a friend, plus a programmer)

Regarding B: If you want two people here, use "I talked to two people: a friend and a programmer." "A friend and a programmer" will be a non-restrictive appositive for "two people."

If you want one person and no ambiguity, you could write "I talked to my friend, a programmer" or "I talked to my friend, who is a programmer," or "I talked to a programmer, who is a friend." Other options are possible.

None of these is a case of the serial comma creating confusion. For example of that, see "A Serial Comma Creates Confusion" - http://zencomma.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/a-serial-comma-creates-confusion/

Answer (score 1):

This could be considered as an example of ambiguity introduced by an [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_comma#Ambiguity).

Answer (score 1):

The most famous *comma* in Irish history led to Roger Casement being hanged for treason.

See http://www.irishhistorycompressed.com/significant-commas-in-irish-history/

> […] if a Man do levy War against our Lord the King in his Realm or be adherent to the King’s Enemies in his Realm giving to them Aid and Comfort in the Realm or elsewhere […]

vs

> if a Man do levy War against our Lord the King in his Realm, or be adherent to the King’s Enemies in his Realm, giving to them Aid and Comfort in the Realm, or elsewhere […]

Inclusion of the comma in the second version, i.e. "**, or elsewhere**" not "**or elsewhere**" resulted in a death sentence.

Comment: I cannot see the difference in meaning. Please elaborate? They basically said "within or outside the realm". I do not see how a pause modifies that. If a waiter said "you may dine indoors... or out" the pause doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well from the article: *Even if Casement had attempted to levy war against the King or to join the King’s enemies, Casement done so in Germany , not “in his Realm”. Casement’s fate, therefore, depended on exactly which part of the text that single mention of “elsewhere” referred to — or did not refer to.* The judge used that as justification to execute Casement.

Comment: Thank you. I am unclear on how different parts of the text are alluded to by the use of the comma, perhaps I am too stupid. I think that the meaning of the statement is that one may execute a traitor wherever they might have been when doing the acts, and wherever one might find them. This is the modern-day interpretation of any sort of fundamentalism. It means that we have decided we have absolute knowledge and power. A small pause makes no difference... Does it?

Comment: Casement did his treason outside the realm. The court used the controversial comma to say that treason could be done **inside the realm or elsewhere** hence he committed treason despite doing it outside the UK.

Comment: Still can't understand. I am just glad I have not committed treason, here or there, or anywhere.