# Does the last comma change the meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, commas, confusables

This got me in a big fight
:

> Mostly I don't want to be hated, for things I wouldn't consider doing, again.

Having the last comma I thought it would refer to being hated again, the reader sent it back with no comma.

> Mostly I don't want to be hated, for things I wouldn't consider doing again."

The reader was under the impression I have already done things i would never consider doing.

Does the comma make it about being hated?
Was there a better way to write the sentence?

Comment: put the 'again' after 'hated'.

Comment: Punctuation can take you only so far. The comma didn't matter to your reader, so how about an explicit statement: *Mostly I don't want to be hated again for things I not only have never done but wouldn't even consider doing*

Comment: That looks like the infamous comma that got Roger Casement executed for treason. See my answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/316701/131620 or the link at  http://www.irishhistorycompressed.com/significant-commas-in-irish-history/

Comment: Punctuation doesn't much matter in the above since most readers will ignore it due to the failure to properly capitalize.

Comment: @HotLicks Since I find this question interesting I've (hopefully) fixed OP's capitalisation to perhaps avoid off-putting future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The reader was mistaken and you were correct. The commas delineate an aside (there is a more proper term for this, but you will get my meaning if I call that part of the sentence between your two commas an "aside"). Removing the second comma obviously changes the meaning of the sentence, and considering your intent aligns with the first construction of the sentence, it is the construction you should use.

Personally I would omit "again" altogether unless there's some special reason it needs to be mentioned that the hatred would be renewed another time.